# How to use the same singleton instance from main appdomain in childs appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have a reference to a singleton (CacheLayer ) from a class (InnerModuleInfoLoader) loaded inside a child domain.
The problem is that this reference is not the same instance as for the rest of the code living in main domain. 
I wonder if exists any way to circumvent the execution isolation of appDomain to use the instance of the singleton?

Here is the code:

```
AppDomain subdomain = this.CreatedChildDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
```

Instantiating class from subdomain

```
var loader = (InnerModuleInfoLoader) subdomain.
    CreateInstanceFrom(loaderType.Assembly.Location, loaderType.FullName).Unwrap();
```

Inside InnerModuleInfoLoader: Bellow I would like that CacheLayer.Instance will be the same for parent and subdomains.

```
var server = CacheLayer.Instance.Get<string>("Server");
```

Singleton

```
public sealed class CacheLayer
{
    private static readonly CacheLayer instance = new CacheLayer();
    private static readonly ObjectCache cache;
    static CacheLayer()
    {
        cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }
    private CacheLayer(){}
    //More code omitted
}
```

Subdomain creation

```
protected virtual AppDomain CreatedChildDomain(AppDomain parentDomain)
{
    Evidence evidence = new Evidence(parentDomain.Evidence);
    AppDomainSetup setup = parentDomain.SetupInformation;
    return AppDomain.CreateDomain("ModuleFinder", evidence, setup);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if exists any way to circumvent the execution isolation of appDomain to use the instance of the singleton?

You can use [`MarshalByRefObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx), that is, make your CacheLayer class inherit from it.

Keep in mind, marshaling calls between AppDomains comes at a performance penalty. I would consider just having two difference caches for each AppDomain.

Comment: agreed, you would be using remoting to communicate, every object passed between the domains would be serialized etc.. not to mention other remoting/proxy issues.  Do it only if you know what you're doing. =)

Comment: So if MarshalByRefObject is the only way I prefer not to use it. I will have to rely in some other stuffs to share data across appdomain, maybe User Settings comes handy here.